# How to extract values from Database using regex and store in CSV in jmeter

Tags: regex, database, csv, jmeter

I m new to Jmeter and stuck on to a specific problem.

My requirement: 
Validate the data from API response in Jmeter with the values in DB(Manually).I am able to validate API's using some assertion but need to execute multiple test and queries which dynamically validates based on the inputs that I provide.

I am able to connect to my DB and execute query and get response in the Response data. However when I try to Use regular expression it requires a start and end point to find the data but I want the data to be captured from the column and store it in a Variable or CSV file. I am unable to dynamically read the entire value of 1 or multiple columns.

Comment: Please post sample code to get a better response.

Comment: It sounds like regex would not be the best solution. But without your code  it is not possible to know for sure.

Comment: There is no Code which I have written for this activity, All I need to know is how do I extract column value and store it in a variable using jmeter? regex is not helpful here.

Comment: I wrote a following Beanshell using regex but is not useful. as for regex I need to specify a start and end point to find the data but I want entire value to be captured from the column and stored in a Variable.                                                         Product = vars.get("Product_ID");
f = new FileOutputStream("C:/Test/DB-Result.csv");
p = new PrintStream(f);
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
print(Product);
f.close();

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any Regex or Beanshell for this, JDBC Request Sampler alone should be enough.

For instance, given the following response:

```
mysql> select Name,Population from city limit 2;
+----------+------------+
| Name     | Population |
+----------+------------+
| Kabul    |    1780000 |
| Qandahar |     237500 |
+----------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can configure JDBC Request Sampler as follows:

If you put the following values:

`Name, Population`

Into "Variable Names" input field

[image: Variable Names]

You will be able to refer cell values as follows:

- `${Name_1}` - for "Kabul"
- `${Name_2}` - for "Qandahar"
- `${Population_1}` - for "1780000"
- `${Population_2}` - for "237500"

[image: Variable values]

References:

- [JDBC Request Sampler Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter)

Comment: Very Clear Explanation and resolves my issue as well :-)

Comment: On the above example.. if i want to randomly specify index and assign it to new variable that can be substituted into by API attribute, in that case, what can i do?

Example: ${Name_1} --> here 1 should be random. 
i tried generating random number and tried substituting in place of 1, but only 1 getting substituted but, database value is empty.